# Glassfish JDBCRealm and request.login()

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I'm having some problems logging users in using a realm and request.login(), I have found some similar questions but none that solve my problem.

Login.xhtml

```
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel for="usernameInput">
                #{bundle['login.email']}:
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputText id="usernameInput" value="#{loginBean.email}" 
                         required="true" />
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel for="passwordInput">
                #{bundle['login.password']}:
            </h:outputLabel>
            <h:inputSecret id="passwordInput" value="#{loginBean.password}" 
                           required="true" />
            <br />
            <h:commandButton value="${bundle['login.submit']}" 
                             action="#{loginBean.login}" />
        </h:form>
```

loginBean.java

```
@Stateless
@Named
public class LoginBean {

@EJB
private UserFacadeREST ejbRef;

private String email;
private String password;

public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String login() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
                                context.getExternalContext().getRequest();

    User user = getUser(this.email);

    if (user != null) {
        hashPassword();
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(this.email));
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(this.password));

        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(user.getEmail()));
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(user.getPassword()));

        if (user.getPassword().equals(this.password)) {
            try {
                request.login(this.email, this.password);
            } catch (ServletException e) {
                context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login failed."));
                return "error";
            }
            return "admin/index";

        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Incorrect password"));
        }

    } else {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("There is no account "
                                                    + "with that email"));
    }
    return "error";
}

public void logout() {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)
                                context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    try {
        request.logout();
    } catch (ServletException e) {
        context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout failed."));
    }
}

private User getUser(String email) {
    try {
        User user = (User) getEntityManager().
                            createNamedQuery("User.findByEmail").
                            setParameter("email", email).
                            getSingleResult();
        return user;
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        System.err.println("NoResultException" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return ejbRef.getEntityManager();
}

/*
 * md5 password. 
 */
public void hashPassword(){
    try {
        byte[] hash = this.password.getBytes();
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        hash = md.digest(hash);
        StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < hash.length; i++) {
            if ((0xff & hash[i]) < 0x10) {
                hexString.append("0").append(Integer.toHexString((0xFF & hash[i])));
            } else {
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & hash[i]));
            }
        }

        String md5Password = hexString.toString();
        setPassword(md5Password);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/Login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/Login.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint> 

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

glassfish-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server         3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="true"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>

  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>USERS</role-name>
    <group-name>USERS</group-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
  <security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>ADMINS</role-name>
    <group-name>ADMINS</group-name>
  <principal-name>berry</principal-name>
  </security-role-mapping>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

realm setup:

```
Realm Name : JDBCRealm
Class Name : com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm

JAAS Context:jdbcRealm
JNDI: mysql/blueberrysoup
User Table: user
User Name Column: email
Password Column: password
Group Table: groups
Group Name Column: role_name
Password Encryption Algorithm: MD5
Digest Algorithm: MD5
Charset: UTF-8
```

and finally the exception thrown by glassfish:

```
WARNING:   No Principals mapped to Role [ADMIN].
INFO:   Loading application [blueberrysoup] at [/blueberrysoup]
INFO:   blueberrysoup was successfully deployed in 3,944 milliseconds.
WARNING:   WEB9102: Web Login Failed:    com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security   Exception
WARNING:   JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource, /user/error.xhtml.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think here's the clue: `WARNING:   No Principals mapped to Role [ADMIN].` .

In your web.xml file You have:

```
<auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
```

And in your glassfish-web.xml file You have:

```
<security-role-mapping>
<role-name>ADMINS</role-name>
<group-name>ADMINS</group-name>
```

As I undersand this mechanism, You have to map roles from web.xml to group name in glassfish-web.xml. The role name in both files should be the same. Also check, if role name for given user in database table is correct.

Here You have some resources:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/security-webapps.html
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/security.html

Comment: Fixed above mentioned "typo" and yes the role mane is correct in the db, but still no success. Got rid of the "WARNING:   No Principals mapped to Role [ADMIN]." error tho.